# Pickling cv2.Knearest objects not working

Tags: python, opencv, pickle

I have been  trying to save a cv2.knearest trained model to file .For the code below (python 2)

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
import pickle
from sklearn.externals import joblib
samples = np.float32(np.loadtxt('feature_vector_pixels.data'))
responses = np.float32(np.loadtxt('samples_pixels.data'))
model = cv2.KNearest()
model.train(samples, responses)
# save the model to disk
filename = 'init_model.sav'
pickle.dump(model, open(filename, 'wb'))
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "picklemake.py", line 14, in <module>
pickle.dump(model, open(filename, 'wb'))
File "C:\Users\Karthik\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\pickle.py", line 1376, in  dump
Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
File "C:\Users\Karthik\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\pickle.py", line 224, in dump
self.save(obj)
File "C:\Users\Karthik\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\pickle.py", line 306, in save
rv = reduce(self.proto)
File "C:\Users\Karthik\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\copy_reg.py", line 70, in _reduce_ex
raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
TypeError: can't pickle KNearest objects
```

Are there any alternatives to save this model to file.

Also
On using model.save, I get `OpenCV Error: The function/feature is not implemented () in CvStatModel::write, file ..\..\..\modules\ml\src\inner_functions.cpp`

Answer (score 1):

[Knearest](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.8/modules/ml/doc/k_nearest_neighbors.html#cvknearest) extends [CvStatModel](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.8/modules/ml/doc/statistical_models.html#cvstatmodel). The latter has two overloads of the [save(...)](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.8/modules/ml/doc/statistical_models.html#cvstatmodel-save) method that do exactly what you need.

I don't exactly know why, but a rule of thumb is that if you're using the python wrapper over C(++) library, its classes usually won't be pickle'able.

Comment: On using model.save, I get `OpenCV Error: The function/feature is not implemented () in CvStatModel::write, file ..\..\..\modules\ml\src\inner_functions.cpp`

Comment: My bad then. I'm leaving the answer for the record, though it's useless. I don't know how to help you. BTW, add this information to the original question, it's gonna make your chances of getting an answer go up.